# New computer lag when booting Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot, lag

Lately I've composed my new computer. But I have often a problem with the following scenario:

-> after turning on computer, the system (Windows 7 Professional 64-bit) is not getting up (I see a black window)

-> I restart my computer and select the boot in normal mode option

-> the system is getting up and I see this:

[image]

-> I'm restarting my os again and it works fine

What can be the problem?

My computer specifications:

- CPU: Core i7 870 2.93GHz LGA1156
- motherboard: Gigabyte GA-P55A-UD3
- graphic card: Asus GeForce GTX 470 1280MB DDR5/320bit
- RAM: Kingston HyperX KHX1600C9D3K2 4GB
- PSU: Corsair 650W CMPSU-650TXEU BOX
- HDD: HDD Samsung 1TB HD103SJ

My system log: http://www.megaupload.com/?d=4CIDMD82

Answer (score 0):

Video card problem in my opinion. Did you connect all the power connectors to your VGA? (okay if you don't connect them it wouldn't even power on.. ignore this stupid idea, just contact reseller!) If yes, you should contact the reseller about warranty. (Seriously this is not a simple driver issue or anything like that.)

Comment: Agreed. Try another screen as well, just to be sure.

Comment: Yeah.. it won't hurt. (it looks like the screen is perfectly fine.)

Comment: The screen is new and is working fine with my laptop. It might be the graphic card, becouse after and during driver installation I had the biggest problems. I wrote to Asus support, let's see what they say. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So after over one month I'm happy to work on my computer.

What happend? Actualy nothing. The card was tested by Asus and they fond nothing (about 3 weeks). I gave the whole computer (with periphery devices) to the service (3 days) but they also found nothing. The problem, I noticed was only at my home.

I took every electrical device which was not connected to the computer away, I switched to another socked and the problem is gone.